# Server cache/buffer memory is continuously growing and not getting free

Tags: linux, memory, apache-http-server

We are running a server that has the following version specification.

> Linux version 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
> (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat
> 4.8.5-16)

The server runs the following major applications running.

> 1. Apache (PHP) - Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) | PHP Version
>    => 5.4.16
> 2. MySQL - 5.5.68-MariaDB
> 3. SOLR - solr-6.3.0

Apache contains our own PHP based application which is a kind of a search engine that filters records based on a like search. The database contains millions of data. As usual MySQL stores data and SOLR keep the indexes to enhance the searching performance. Additionally, we have a feature to do bulk upload files which can be hundreds of Megabytes.

The application has been deployed on the server since the year 2018 and was all good since January 2022.

Suddenly from January 2022, we are observing that server cache/buffer is gradually increasing but not getting free. Please refer to the memory info.

```
$ free -h
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           9.6G        2.5G        446M        569M        6.7G        6.1G
    Swap:          4.9G        342M        4.6G

$ free -w -h
                  total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
    Mem:           9.6G        2.5G        419M        569M          0B        6.7G        6.2G
    Swap:          4.9G        342M        4.6G
```

When we manually clear the buffer/cache using the command `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, buff/cache memory gets cleared. But gradually it starts to grow and arrive at the above state within around 24 hours or less. It doesn't get free. Then our PHP based application begins to function slowly and we get HTTP 504 errors continuously.

1. Why is the buff/cache memory doesn't get free on-demand?
2. If this is a memory leak, apparently at which level the memory leak can be available (OS or application)?
3. What are the approaches I can follow to debug this issue furthermore?

Comment: Please provide the output of `free -w` when the error is happening. In the data you show, it’s almost all cache. You want cache.

Comment: @DanielB updated the question with your required info. Please check

Comment: Are you using ZFS?

Comment: @Gantendo ZFS is not used

Comment: Is it possible that there a problem with the expiration times on your website(s)? See the article [Improve Website Performance by Enabling Caching in Apache](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/improve-website-performance-by-enabling-caching-in-apache/) and especially regarding `CacheDefaultExpire` and Mod_Expires.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> we are observing that server cache/buffer is gradually increasing but not getting free.

That's normal, Linux will use all available memory for buffer/cache, and only free it when needed. It will never get freed "automatically", you'll never see a substantial decrease during normal operation.

> Then our PHP based application begins to function slowly

I have been observing a similar problem on my machine for a long time now: Sometimes the system I/O gets slow, and dropping buffers makes it fast again. I suspect a kernel bug in buffer management, but so far I haven't seen a fix (and the fix, if someone figures it out, won't change the Linux behaviour to use all the memory it has).

But of course your problem may be unrelated to my problem.

Comment: Dirk, interesting ... I just [posted about I/O becoming slow over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74978959/fwrite-becomes-slow-after-long-uptime) and since then have been looking for memory leaks in our software. One thing I noticed is that just repeatedly doing free (cmd line) shows buffers increasing by 4 every 30 sec or so. Searching on that led me to your answer. If anything in my post rings a bell feel free to ask / comment